# A global function to be executed before opening a form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class, function

I have around 15 forms and every form includes some similar piece of codes.

What i want to know is that there is any way to automatically call a function containing that particular piece of code when a form is opening?

Like, lets say i want to show `Hello World` message every time when any form of a project is loaded.

So what i can do is i can create a module or class file and i can add a piece of code their and i can call it in every form.

But this i don't want, what i want is that, is there any way where i can add this piece of code and automatically it gets populated/triggered when a form gets loaded.

**Maybe we can call it something like - auto calling function for forms**

Like, whenever a form is opening automatically a class or function gets called without defining it in the particular form. Maybe a library kind of thing which will be called anyways when a form is loaded and i can add my piece of code there and it gets executed.

Comment: Can you derive all your forms off a single base class - which in turn is derived from the original inherited class?  Then you can have something in the constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own base class inheriting from form:

```
public abstract class FormBase : Form { /*...*/ }
```

Then every form you are using may inherit from this base class:

```
public class MyForm : FormBase { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: Where do i need to add this code? And do i need to anything to all the forms to make it executable?

Comment: Well - without being offensive - you should probably read some introduction into object orientated programming.. inheritance is very basic to oop.

Comment: Yes but i am unable to figure out, how it can solve my problem in this condition also i am manually defining the inheritance to each and every form. I want is there anything we can do like, whenever a form is opening automatically a class or function gets called without defining it in the particular form. Maybe a library kind of thing which will be called anyways when a form is loaded and i can add my piece of code there and it gets executed.

Comment: Inheritance is the most "automatic" way you can go here.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event handler to the form, and put whatever code needs to be run in there.

For Example:

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.FormName_Load);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class frm_Base : Form
{
  public void frm_Base()
  {
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.frm_Base_Load);
  }
  public void frm_Base_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    OnFormLoad();
  }
  public virtual OnFormLoad()
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
  }
}
public class frm_Derived : frm_Base
{
  public override OnFormLoad()
  {
    base.OnFormLoad();
    MessageBox.Show("Another Hello From Derived");
  }
}
```

You can now inherit the functionality that happens on load in all of your other forms as well as do other things too by making your load method virtual.

Comment: Do i need to add it into my project module?